# Raspberry pi load app at startup / Raspberry pi cargar app al iniciar

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, electron

My project is in /home/pi/app
Starts with npm start

How can I get the app to start up when I start the operating system?

Service => it does not work

```
[Unit]
Description=appvi
After=netwwork-online.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/appvi
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/npm start
Restart=always
StandardOuput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=notell
User=pi
Group=pi
Enviroment=NODE_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I think this question should be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the rc.local file, https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md