# How to use Cron and Crontab in raspberry to program electron

Tags: node.js, npm, cron, raspberry-pi, electron

I need an electron application to start loading the operating system.

At the beginning.

*** Español

Necesito que una aplicación electron se inicie al cargar el sistema operativo.

Al inicio.

it does not work

```
@reboot sleep 400  &&  /home/pi/appvi/app.sh
```

app.sh

```
cd /home/pi/appvi/
npm start
```

Comment: What you need is a system service for your app. Take a look at [systemd](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md)

Comment: Eso también lo he realizado y no me arranca https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762805/raspberry-pi-load-app-at-startup-raspberry-pi-cargar-app-al-iniciar . No sé si estará bien realizado